# How to save image from Canvas to BlobStore in GWT  Google App Engine

Tags: image, google-app-engine, canvas, blobstore

now I'm stuck in this issue. I'm using Canvas HTML5 to  draw an Image to Canvas then I have some customization with that canvas. For the next step, I want to save that Canvas (image) to BlobStore of Google App Engine. But now I dont know how to do that. So can you please help me here.
Thanks for your help!
Have a nice day.
Michael Vu